# How to check if writing task was successful in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm totally new to Firebase and need to know how to check if my writing task was successful because if I don't, the `MainActivity` starts and messes up my `Register` progress.

This checks if `Username` is already taken and registers the user if it isn't:

```
Query usernamequery = myRef.orderByChild("Username").equalTo(Username);

usernamequery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            // TODO: handle the case where the data already exists
            editText.setError("Username taken!");
            return;
        }
        else {
            // TODO: handle the case where the data does not yet exist
            myRef.child("Users").child(Username).child("Userid").setValue(user.getUid());
            myRef.child("Users").child(Username).child("Username").setValue(Username);
            startActivity(maps);
            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        Toast.makeText(Username.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

But I want the Intent to Main Activity (maps) only be fired when 
`myRef.child("Users").child(Username).child("Userid").setValue(user.getUid());`

and the other one is finished with its task and is successful.

What can I do?

Comment: put a listener on the value changing, and when it changes then start your other activity.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To know when a write operation has completed on the server, add a completion listener:

```
myRef.child("Users").child(Username).child("Userid").setValue(user.getUid(), new DatabaseReference.CompletionListener() {
    void onComplete(DatabaseError error, DatabaseReference ref) {
        System.err.println("Value was set. Error = "+error);
        // Or: throw error.toException();
    }
});
```

If there was an error, details will be in the `error` operation. If the write operation was completed without problems, the `error` will be `null`.

If you want to write to multiple locations with a single operation, you'll want to look at the [`update()` method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data)

The correct overload for `setValue()` is documented [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/DatabaseReference.html#setValue(java.lang.Object,%20com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.CompletionListener)).

Comment: But how can I re-attach `DatabaseReference.CompletionListener` after the configuration changes (an old `Activity` has been destroyed and a new one created)?

Comment: If operation has failed, an error will be given. If it has succeeded, the error will be null